# Python Pandas conditional value elimination

Tags: python, dataframe

I am trying to drop values in one data frame based on value-based on another data frame. I would appreciate your expertise on this, please.
Data frame 1 – df1:

```
| A        | C              |
| -------- | -------------- |
| f        | 10             |
| c        | 15             |
| b        | 20             |
| d        | 30             |
| h        | 35             |
| e        | 40             |
-----------------------------
```

Data frame 2 – df2:

```
| A        | B              |
| -------- | -------------- |
| a        | w              |
| b        | 1              |
| c        | w              |
| d        | 1              |
| e        | w              |
| f        | 0              |
| g        | 1              |
| h        | 1              |
-----------------------------
```

I want to modify the df1 and drop(eliminate) values in column A if corresponding values in column B is ‘w’ in df2.
Resulted data frame looks like below.

```
| A        | C              |
| -------- | -------------- |
| f        | 10             |
| b        | 20             |
| d        | 30             |
| h        | 35             |
-----------------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first create a `list` from `df2` with the values of `A` that have associated value of `'w'` in `B`, and then use `isin` and `~` (which means *not in* essentially):

```
a = df2.loc[df2['B'].str.contains(r'w',case=False,na=False),'A'].tolist()
b = df1[~df1['A'].isin(a)]
```

And get back your desired outcome:

```
print(b)

   A   C
0  f  10
2  b  20
3  d  30
4  h  35
```

I find this link particularly helpful if you want to read more on `Python's operators`:
https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_operators.asp

Comment: Another issue: if some values in df1 column are different from the description in df2 or not entirely in df2 column A, how could I keep them in the final df?

Comment: I think this changes your final outcome then. To make it clearer, could you update your question so that I can work towards getting the new result?

Comment: Apologies, I am new to this

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is a `merge` with certain conditions:

```py
# recreating your data
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'A': list('fcbdhe'), 'B': [10, 15, 20, 30, 35, 40]})
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'A': list('abcdefgh'), 'B': list('w1w1w011')})

# merge but we further need to project that to fit the desired output
>>> df1.merge(df2[df2['B'] != 'w'], how='inner', on='A')
   A  B_x B_y
0  f   10   0
1  b   20   1
2  d   30   1
3  h   35   1

# what you're looking for
>>> df1.merge(df2[df2['B'] != 'w'], how='inner', on='A')[['A', 'B_x']].rename(columns={'B_x': 'C'})
   A   C
0  f  10
1  b  20
2  d  30
3  h  35
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your first dataframe is df1 and second dataframe is df2.

First of all, list all the values of column A of df2 that value is 'w' in column B of df2.

```
df2_A = df2[df2['B'] == 'w']['A'].values.tolist()

# >>>output = ['a','c','e']
```

It will list all the values of column A of df2 that has value 'w' in column B of df2.

Then you can drop the values of df1 whose values lies in the list of above.

```py
for i, val in enumerate(df1['A'].values.tolist()):
  if val in df2_A:
    df1.drop(i, axis=0, inplace=True)
```

Full code:

```py
df2_A = df2[df2['B'] == 'w']['A'].values.tolist()

for i, val in enumerate(df1['A'].values.tolist()):
  if val in df2_A:  #checking if A column of df1 has values similar to above list
    df1.drop(i, axis=0, inplace=True)

df1
```

Comment: The second part of the code doesn't do anything. It looks logical to me but somehow it doesn't do anything, no error code. I use JN.

Comment: @PrageethWarnasinghege you mean that for loop part? It will drop the rows from df1 whose values match with df2 column A

Comment: Hi Prakash, yes, the code makes sense but it doesn't do anything

Answer (score 0):

```
df1.merge(df2[df2['B']!='w'],how='inner').drop(["B"], axis=1)
```